# Custom Watermarks with Apache Flink

Tags: apache-flink

I am investigating the types of watermarks that can be inserted into the data stream.

While this may go outside of the purpose of watermarks, I'll ask it anyway.

Can you create a watermark that holds a timestamp and k/v pair(s) `(this=that, that=this)`?

Hence the watermark will hold `{12DEC180500GMT,this=that, that=this}`.

Or

`{Timestamp, kvp1, kvp2, kvpN}`

Is something like this possible? I have reviewed the user and API docs but may have overlooked something

Comment: I don't believe the API is designed to accommodate that, but perhaps if you explain why you would find this useful an alternative implementation will come to mind.

Comment: @DavidAnderson Hopefully the diagram and commentary I added will help clarify. https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bw69DO1tid2_SzVVendtUV9WMVdIUXptQ1hHSl9KNjAyMTBn/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: That drive file isn't publicly accessible.

Comment: @DavidAnderson it's available now.

Comment: @DavidAnderson, just changed the setting to allow anyone with the link to access.

Comment: Interesting. I recommend you take this question to the Flink User mailing list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the Watermark class in Flink 
(found in 
flink/flink-streaming/java/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/api/watermark/Watermark.java) 
has one one instance variable besides MAX_WATERMARK, which is

```
/** The timestamp of the watermark in milliseconds. */
private final long timestamp;
```

So watermarks cannot carry any information besides a timestamp, which must be a long value.

Comment: This is the actual answer. I am wondering if this is something that could be useful

Comment: Depending on where the values for this and that come from, there are ways to access the data. If the data comes from the events in the stream, they can be extracted from the events when needed. If they are constant variables, they could be defined elsewhere in the code and used. If they are dynamic values, you could create create a stream of the different this and that values and connect this to your original string. Is there another situation you are thinking of?